# How to test my app with incorrect SSL certificate?

Tags: android, testing, ssl, man-in-the-middle

I have an Android app using tcp connection with my server in the cloud. I was required to make test to check how my client response to wrong certifications. I do not have any access to the server in the cloud.

Are there any way to intercept or any method to change certifications before getting to my client (Man in the Middle ...)?

Comment: Use a different URL for your tests, one that points to a server with an invalid certificate (e.g., some test server on your test machine with a self-signed certificate). If your code does not support replacing the URL based upon whether it is a test build or a production build, add it.

Comment: Is your app using a custom `TrustManager`? If so, you could cause a failure in it using the test build as suggested by CommonsWare.